# Python 2.7 on System, PIP and Virtualenv still using 2.6 - How do I switch them to use 2.7

Tags: python, macos, virtualenv, pip

I am on MacOSx 10.6.8 and I have python 2.7 installed

python -v produces:

```
Python 2.7.2 (v2.7.2:8527427914a2, Jun 11 2011, 15:22:34) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
dlopen("/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/readline.so", 2);
import readline # dynamically loaded from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/readline.so
```

I them run:

```
$ virtualenv venv
```

and then

```
$ . venv/bin/activate
```

and do a python -v

and I get:

```
Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Jun 24 2010, 21:47:49) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
dlopen("/Users/nkhdev/venv/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/readline.so", 2);
import readline # dynamically loaded from /Users/nkhdev/venv/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/readline.so
```

Can someone tell me the steps to use have virtualenv create and use python 2.7 from my system?  Or have virtualenv, use python 2.7 period.  I don't care if the version is my system version.

Comment: I really think this belongs on superuser.com

Comment: In each environment, check what `which python` returns. Actually, `type -a python` will probably be more illustrative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably used an existing, Apple-supplied version of `easy_install` to install `pip` et al.  By default, `easy_install` is associated with a particular instance of Python, in this case, the Apple-supplied system Python 2.6.  In general, when you install a new version of Python, you need to also install a new `easy_install` for it.  Follow [the instructions here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute) for the Distribute package which provides `easy_install`, then use it to install `pip` and use that `pip` to install `virtualenv`.

Answer (score 0):

My *guess* is that both pip and virtualenv are from the 2.6 distro. You can check which one the system users with `which pip`. If you do have other pip/virtualenv install (use `which -a pip` to find all of them) it might be that you need to tweak your `PATH` environment variable.

Another thing to note is the installed Python scripts usually have full path to the Python executable. You can see which python pip is using by running `head $(which pip)`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, virtualenv python was picking up the 2.7.6 system python from `/usr/bin/python` rather than the 2.7.9 version in `/usr/local/bin/python`

I had to do:

```
sudo pip uninstall virtualenv
```

Then I installed setuptools like so:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -o - | python
```

Then I installed pip with that new version of setuptools like so:

```
easy_install pip
```

Then I installed virtualenv

```
pip install --upgrade virtualenv
```