# Pip version limbo

Tags: python, macos, pip

I basically have the exact same situation as described in
[Python 2.7 on System, PIP and Virtualenv still using 2.6 - How do I switch them to use 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10055260/165673)

That is, my mac is using Python 2.7 as default, while Pip is installing to 2.6

I followed [Ned Deily's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10055615/165673) and installed easy_install with my default Python, and used that to install Pip.

**Now I get:**

```
$ which easy_install
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/easy_install  
$ which pip
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pip
```

**Alright, looking good. But, I also get this:**

```
$ pip --version
pip 1.0.2 from /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pip-1.0.2-py2.6.egg (python 2.6)
```

and Pip is *still* installing to 2.6.

What am I missing?

---

**Update**:

Maybe this is a clue- I just ran the following:

```
$ ls -la /usr/bin/python*  
-rwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel  86000 May  4  2011 /usr/bin/python  
-rwxr-xr-x  5 root  wheel    925 May  4  2011 /usr/bin/python-config  lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     75 May  4  2011 /usr/bin/python2.5 ->
../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/bin/python2.5
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     82 May  4  2011
/usr/bin/python2.5-config ->
../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/bin/python2.5-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     75 May  4  2011 /usr/bin/python2.6 ->
../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python2.6
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     82 May  4  2011
/usr/bin/python2.6-config ->
../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python2.6-config
-rwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel  86000 May  4  2011 /usr/bin/pythonw lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     76 May  4  2011 /usr/bin/pythonw2.5 ->
../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/bin/pythonw2.5
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     76 May  4  2011 /usr/bin/pythonw2.6 ->
../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/pythonw2.6
```

and

```
$ ls -la /usr/local/bin/python*     
lrwxr-xr-x  1 ykessler  wheel  68
Nov 14  2011 /usr/local/bin/python ->
../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
lrwxr-xr-x  1 ykessler  wheel  71 Nov 14  2011
/usr/local/bin/python-32 ->
../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python-32
lrwxr-xr-x  1 ykessler  wheel  75 Nov 14  2011
/usr/local/bin/python-config ->
../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 ykessler  wheel  71 Nov 14  2011
/usr/local/bin/python2.7 ->
../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
lrwxr-xr-x  1 ykessler  wheel  74 Nov 14  2011
/usr/local/bin/python2.7-32 ->
../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7-32
lrwxr-xr-x  1 ykessler  wheel  78 Nov 14  2011
/usr/local/bin/python2.7-config ->
../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 ykessler  wheel  69 Nov 14  2011 /usr/local/bin/pythonw
-> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pythonw
lrwxr-xr-x  1 ykessler  wheel  72 Nov 14  2011
/usr/local/bin/pythonw-32 ->
../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pythonw-32
lrwxr-xr-x  1 ykessler  wheel  72 Nov 14  2011
/usr/local/bin/pythonw2.7 ->
../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pythonw2.7
lrwxr-xr-x  1 ykessler  wheel  75 Nov 14  2011
/usr/local/bin/pythonw2.7-32 ->
../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pythonw2.7-32
```

So it looks like my user environment is pointing to 2.7, but root environment pointing to 2.6? How do I reconcile these two?

---

**Update 2:**

OK, just to turn the screw a little more:

```
$ sudo pip --version  
pip 1.2.1 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)
$ pip --version  
pip 1.0.2 from /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pip-1.0.2-py2.6.egg (python 2.6)
```

so my root points to 2.6 but `sudo pip --version` points to pip 2.7,
while my local user points to 2.7 but `pip --version` points to pip 2.6

??? My brains starting to fry.

Now I just did `sudo pip install {module}` and it installed correctly in 2.7, but I wish I knew what was going on...

---

**Update 3: Answer to Ned's question:**

```
$ type pip  
pip is /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pip  
$ echo $PATH  
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin  
$ which pip  
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pip  
$ ls -l $(which pip)  
-rwxr-xr-x  1 ykessler  admin  358 Oct  3 15:30 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pip  
$ sudo bash  
bash-3.2# type pip  
pip is /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pip  
bash-3.2# echo $PATH  
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin  
bash-3.2# ls -l $(which pip)  
-rwxr-xr-x  1 ykessler  admin  358 Oct  3 15:30 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pip
```

Comment: what python is listed on `head /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pip`?

Comment: @Martijn: #!/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python

Comment: And if you run `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pip --version` directly? Your path seems rather mucked up that it finds the Python 2.6 version still.

Comment: @Martijn: Correct, pointing to it directly will display the right version. I'm just not sure how the default path could point to 2.7 on `which` but 2.6 on execution

Comment: Do you have a shell alias defined for `pip`?  What does `echo $PATH` give in the same shell that give you the `pip` pointing at Python 2.6?

Comment: @Ned- `echo $PATH`
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm guessing he's doing `sudo pip` which is inheriting the system environment which points to 2.6 rather than his user environment pointing to 2.7 Python.

Comment: Yes, if you are using `sudo` that would change things.  Else check `type pip` and `env | grep PYTHON`.

Comment: Guys, see my update- the exact opposite actually happened- `sudo pip` *did* work, which makes absolutely no sense to me..

Comment: UPDATE - THE NEXT DAY: Now pip is pointing to and installing in 2.7. No idea what changed. Thank you guys for your help.

Answer (score 1):

On my system, I have several easy_installs:

```
$ ls /usr/bin/easy_install*
/usr/bin/easy_install       /usr/bin/easy_install-2.5   /usr/bin/easy_install-2.6   /usr/bin/easy_install-2.7
```

As well as several pips:

```
$ ls /usr/local/bin/pip*
/usr/local/bin/pip  /usr/local/bin/pip-2.5  /usr/local/bin/pip-2.6  /usr/local/bin/pip-2.7
```

As you said, you seem to have your user environment pointing to 2.7, but system is pointing to 2.6. As I see it, you have two options:

1. You can monkey with Apple settings to switch your system python version: `$ defaults write com.apple.versioner.python Version 2.7` or `$ export VERSIONER_PYTHON_VERSION=2.7`. (See [`man python`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/python.1.html) for more details on your specific version of OSX.)
2. You can use the pip python specific version. (For example: `pip-2.7`)

Comment: You can't use `VERSIONER_PYTHON_VERSION` to point to a non-Apple-installed Python, AFAIK.

Comment: @NedDeily True. But from the looks of his pathnames above, he's using an Apple-installed 2.7 Python.

Comment: @akraut- no Ned's right- i installed python 2.7 myself to work with GAE, but was many moons ago

Comment: It doesn't to me.  Note, `/Library/Frameworks/` not `/System/Library/Frameworks`.  And Apple doesn't include things like `python-32` in their framework bin directory.

Comment: @arkaut - thanks for suggestion 2 though- assuming that would work, though I ended up getting it working with `sudo`, without understanding why...

Answer (score 1):

You may have either a $PATH issue or a permissions issue or both.  Try this:

```
type pip
echo $PATH
which pip
ls -l $(which pip)
sudo bash
type pip
echo $PATH
ls -l $(which pip)
```

Update: one more thing to try under both:

```
env | grep PYTHON
sudo bash
env | grep PYTHON
```

Then I would look at the contents of the `site-packages` directory:

```
cd /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7
cd ./lib/python2.7/site-packages/
ls -al
more setuptools.pth
```

Also:

```
more $(which pip)
python2.7 -c 'import sys, pprint; pprint.pprint(sys.path)'
sudo python2.7 -c 'import sys, pprint; pprint.pprint(sys.path)'
```

Comment: I posted the results under `update 3` in my question. All point to 2.7... ?

Comment: Well, needless to say, it can all be made to work correctly. But, at this point with the various steps you've taken, it's hard to tell what was going on without getting into all the details of exactly what Python you installed, what easy_install version and source (setuptools vs Distribute), which pip version, when you used sudo or not, exactly what the contents of your `site-packages` directory is, what environment variable settings were in effect etc.  Perhaps one more thing to check: do you have a `~/.pydistutils.cfg` file and if so what is its contents?

Comment: no. But this morning suddenly pip is pointing to and installing in 2.7! I really have no idea what's changed, but I very much appreciate your help.