# How I get all my Python tools to use the latest Python?

Tags: macos, python-2.7, configuration, path

Following the recommendation on python.org, I recently installed Python 2.7.6 on my Mac OS X (10.9) machine. As I understand, this created an entirely new version of Python, independent of existing ones (in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/`) added its `bin` directory to my `PATH`, and created symlinks to its command line tools in `/usr/local/bin`.

But this only results in a partial update. All tools belonging to other packages — for example `pip`, `yolk` and `ipython` — still use the "old" Python. It seems this can be traced to the first line of the launch scripts for these tools in `/usr/local/bin`, which reads

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

I know that could ensure that these tools "track" this and any future python.org updates by changing this line to

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

but can't imagine that editing each of the files for all of my tools in this way is the intended approach. In particular it means that while everything I've written (which uses `#!/usr/bin/env python`) is running with the version of Python I'm configured to use, none of Python's tools are!

How do I ensure that after installing a new version of Python, my tools — such as `pip`, `ipython` and `yolk` — will use the version of Python that *I'm* using?

---

This is **not** a question about `virtualenv`, but about the base configuration without it.

Comment: @Wooble: Sorry, I was just about to add the note above that I'm not looking for `virtualenv` solutions. But I'd entertain answers that show how to solve this issue using `virtualenv` if they show me how to "update" in this way, leaving all the packages I've installed already where they are and accessible, and simply ensuring that the latest (here for example bug-fixed) Python is the "default" and used throughout.

Comment: @Wooble: Also, it isn't clear to me from reading the documentation for `virtualenv` that it would solve my problem. Wouldn't the `#!/usr/bin/python` line in `pip`, `ipython`, etc. still launch the "old" system-installed Python, regardless of any other path's I'd set or environments I'd configured?

Comment: virtualenv installs its own `pip` for the environment. No idea about ipython.

Comment: @Wooble: So for for now (for the sake of this question) let's stay away from 'virtualenv'. Here the focus is just on how, having — I think (and would like to confirm) - gotten everything else to "update" by simply adding `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin` (or for that matter, given the symlinks, `/usr/local/bin:` to my `PATH`: how do I get my existing tools to use the "update"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10055260/python-2-7-on-system-pip-and-virtualenv-still-using-2-6-how-do-i-switch-them/10055615#10055615 may help, although it's moving from 2.6 to 2.7 instead of a system 2.7 I think the principle is the same. Basically you need to re-install the tools for the new version (probably in /usr/local).

Comment: @Wooble: So maybe I've got a wrong(ish) model of how Python sets up tools and packages. I was assuming that when a new Python was installed (or switched to, by, say changing the path or creating symlinks) existing tools would "track". But the model seems to be that *each* installation of Python has it's own tools (the ones installed when it was active). If (as I've done thus far) those tools are all in a single place, you have to reinstall them after switching to get them to use a new Python). The "right" way is probably to have a distinct directory for each Python's tools. (Right?)

Comment: Is it sufficient to update `pip`, or reinstall it, in the presence of the new Python configuration? Will all subsequent updates to tools then have their `#!` configured to run the new python?